# Близорукость и дальнозоркость

Tags: этимология

Близорукость — когда человек не видит удаленные предметы, но хорошо видит вблизи. Дальнозоркость — наоборот. Явления одного толка, а корни слов разные — почему так?

Comment: Медицинские термины *близорукий* и *дальнозоркий* появились довольно поздно в русском языке - в 18 и 19 веках соответственно. Когда очков на Руси не было, то не было и специального слова для обозначения **миопии**. Людей, плохо видящих, называли просто слепыми или слепошарыми. Синонимами слова *близорукий* стали : близоглазый, близоокий. Словарь 1847  : "Близорукий - имеющий **короткое зрение**". Мнение БСЭ :
>Название Б. обусловлено тем, что близорукие обычно **держат рассматриваемый предмет близко к глазам.**
В Словаре русского языка **11-17** вв слова *близорукий* или близозоркий - НЕТ.

Comment: @grumant, а как ювелиров называли, "слепошарыми"? Близорукий вблизи такие вещи разглядит, которые человеку с нормальным зрением недоступны. В некоторых профессиях, в том числе и очень древних, небольшая близозоркость - производственная необходимость.

 А в словаре книжных слов 11-17 вв. вы и слово "насморк" вряд ли найдёте. По религиозно-этическим представлениям того времени, всё телесное, не влияющее на душу, считалось недостойным внимания.

Comment: Слово насморк есть в САР (1789) и миллион ему подобных. Взгляните **непредвзято** на слово близорукий и поймите закономерность его прямого и независимого  образования наряду с похожими синонимами - близоглазый, близоокий, слепоокий. Позднее возникло и слово **слепокурый**. Мое мнение не единственное, см. выше (БСЭ, словарь Академии 1847).
безрукий
белорукий
близорукий
большерукий
голорукий
двурукий
длиннорукий
короткорукий
косорукий
криворукий
леворукий
оберукий
однорукий
долгорукий
праворукий
сторукий
сухорукий
тонкорукий
троерукий
четверорукий

Comment: @grumant, 1789 - это конец 18 в, там и близорукий есть. А вы писали про 11-17 вв. После Петра восприятие мира среди элиты поменялось.

Про "близоглазый" и пр., они все для словообразования используют орган, которым видят. Руками люди не видят. Если б этимология была бы связана с позой, то сохранилось бы и выражение, типа, *близоруко держать что-либо*


БСЭ  - это пример, того, что нужно пользоваться специализированной литературой. Написана статья не филологом, а медиком, поэтому сведения этимологии оттуда лучше не подчерпывать. А. Т. Фоменко -  член РАН, но по истории его книги - чушь.

Comment: >Руками люди не видят

 Слепые люди видят
как раз руками, да и слабовидящие все
ручками ощупывают! Любые разговоры о
близозоркости - в пользу классических
старорежимных етимологов, которые ради
красного словца не жалели и родного отца.
Термин близорукий появился в 18 веке, как
синоним к близоокому. И Словарь РЯ 18 в. это
фиксирует. Поставлю точку на этом, писать
исследование - жирно будет.
[История русской офтальмологии](http://eyehospital.ru/view_page.php?page=23)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Изначально было "близозоркость", но для удобства произношения сократилось до "близоркость" (сравни томскский-томский). После "близоркость" преобразовалась в более понятную близорукость. В украинском языке, где звуки не повторялись, так и осталось "близозiркость

Comment: В Вашем в целом правильном объяснении - натяжка по части "удобства произношения". Никаких неудобств повтор звуков не доставляет. 
"Близоркость" произнести едва ли не сложнее.
Да и появление У эта версия никак не объясняет.

Comment: @behemothus, не могу вспомнить как называется, но есть закон в русском языке, по которому не может быть двух одинаковых слогов подряд. Если так происходит, то один из этих слогов выпадает.  Например, суффикс -оват-, присоединяясь к основе розов-, даёт прилагательное "розоватый" вместо ожидаемого "розововатый". Не помню как называется, помню только, что сам вид термина противоречит его значению.

Так вот, по этому закону "близозоркий" перешло в "близоркий", а только после этого под влиянием народной этимологии стало близоруким. тоже самое стало с корноносый (укороченный нос)>корносый>курносый

Comment: Вот только написал и вспомнил термин, "гаплология". По закону гаплологии должен звучать "гаплогия", но в виду сугубой академичности термина, гаплологии "гаплология" избежала.

Comment: >В украинском языке, где звуки не повторялись, так и осталось "близозiркость

Что-то не припоминаю такого слова в украинском языке. Близорукость -- это *короткозорість*. 

Например, как подтверждение, статья о близорукости в укр. Википедии

http://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CA%EE%F0%EE%F2%EA%EE%E7%EE%F0%B3%F1%F2%FC

Comment: @Nikolja, этот вариант даёт Фасмер. Я знаю, что в современном украинском нет такого слова, но современный украинский во многом и создавался по принципу, как можно меньше похожих на русские слов, так что думаю, что 100 лет назад это слово в украинском было почти наверняка.

Comment: >но есть закон в русском языке, по которому не может быть двух одинаковых слогов подряд.  
  
А он есть? что-то не слвшал- именно в такой формулировке. 
Но дело даже не в этом. Если брать ваши примеры, то получается, что речь идет не об упрощении некогда существовавшего слова, а о изначальной невозможности его появления. Это разные вещи. 
Но даже эта подмена не объясняет появление У. Нет, мне объяснение Грамоты определенно больше нравится.

Comment: > По религиозно-
этическим представлениям того времени, всё
телесное, не влияющее на душу, считалось
недостойным внимания.

Хромые, глухие, прокаженные, бл@ди и прочие свободно разгуливают по древнерусским рукописям! Близоруких нет, поелику очков и окулистов царь-батюшка не выписал покудова из-за бугра. Время придет - все сразу появится.

Comment: @grumant, так и слово "близорукие" использовали, по крайней мере в вашей цитате оно есть.

>безрукий белорукий **близорукий** ... 

Вопрос только в каком тексте и частотность. 

А по поводу непредвзятости... Что может означать слово если забыть его значение? Кто-то с близкими руками. Своя рука (не путать с ладонью), всегда на одинаковом расстоянии от тела, значит рука чужая. Семантика "рука" в русском - это ещё и помощник (правая рука, рука помощи) - значит близорукий=помощник в работе. Соответственно в отрыве от корня -зор- слово "близорукий" меняет смысл. И слова "близкодланный" - нет.

Comment: Близорукий - слово появилось в 18 веке, специально для подслеповатых людей, **"имеющих короткое зрение"** (Словарь 1847) Список слов (выше) с корнем **рук** - из современного словаря.

Answer (score 2):

Какова этимология слова близорукий? При чем здесь руки?

Ответ
Прилагательное близорукий восходит к древнерусскому близозоръкъ (буквально: близозоркий; церковнославянский вариант: близозракъ). Близозоркий – "тот, кто видит только вблизи". Ср. аналогичные кривозоркий (косоглазый), дальнозоркий.
А теперь – о том, как в этом слове появилась "рука". Появление этого корня в слове близорукий связано с явлением так называемой народной (или ложной) этимологии – "подгонкой" формы слова под какое-то близкое по звучанию слово (ср. просторечные и встречающиеся в детской речи слова "пузово" вместо "кузов", "спинжак" вместо "пиджак", а также замена исконного "ведмедь" на "медведь", "мед + ведать" и т. п.).  По народной этимологии внутренняя форма слова близорукий – буквально "тот, кто не видит дальше своих рук".
(gramota.ru)

БЛИЗОРУКОСТЬ - слово это, если задуматься, вызывает некоторое недоумение. В самом деле, причем тут рука, которая слышится совершенно явно?
Давным-давно, когда слово только возникло, о руке и речи не шло. Было наречие "близко", было прилагательное "зоркий". Когда их поставили рядом, получилось существительное близозоркость - близковидение. Но слог "зо" выговаривать два раза подряд оказалось неудобно - и на некоторое время в обиход вошло совсем ничего не значащее близоркий. Однако слова, совершенно лишенные внутреннего смысла, плохо уживаются в языке, и постепенно получилось то, что получилось. Былого не вернуть, да и не надо - и так ясно, что такое близорукость. 
(gramma.ru)

Answer (score 0):

в словах близорукость и дальнозоркость явно виден общий корень - зор-, такой же, как в слове *зрение*, только без беглости гласных. Дальнозокость - слово более позднего происхождения и возникло как антоним к слову близорукость. Язык развивается по своим законам. Произошло наложение конечных зо (зъ)- для удобства речи или ещё для чего - мы уже ни у кого не спросим.